# The first timer in a react component list is getting value NaN

Tags: reactjs

I have a React website where I have 2 toggles for different kinds of cards - one of them is Live markets (this type has a timer component).

[image]

Here is the problem- When I switch to classifieds and I switch back to live markets -
Auction timer for the first card becomes NaN. Note: this only happens to the first card, the other timers are fine.

[image]

I have a CardsLayout component, which send a request to the server for data when the above toggle is changed. And if it is in Live Markets tab, then the CardsLayout component maps each object to an AuctionCard component which has a Timer component inside it.

Here is the code for the Timer component-

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Timer({ id, endTime}) {
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(getRemainingTime());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setRemainingTime(getRemainingTime());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  function getRemainingTime() {
    const now = new Date();
    const end = new Date(endTime);
    const diff = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
    const days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const minutes = Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
    return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
  }

  console.log('endtime-',id,endTime)
  console.log('remtime-',id,remainingTime.seconds)

  return (
    <div className={remainingTime.seconds < 0 ? 'timer-ended' : 'timer'}>
      {remainingTime.seconds < 0 ? (
        "Auction over"
      ) : (
        <>
          Auction time remaining: {remainingTime.days} Days {remainingTime.hours}:
          {remainingTime.minutes}:{remainingTime.seconds}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also have 2 console statements. The values are getting printed every second. Here is whats getting printed for the Timer with NaN-

endtime- 4 2023-06-09T20:30:00.000Z

remtime- 4 NaN

Comment: Does it work if you pass `id` and  `endTime` as dependencies in the `useEffect` ? `useEffect(......, [id, endTime]);`

Comment: yes! it stays NaN for a second, then corrects the timer. Can you explain why this works as an Answer so I can mark yours as right and close this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works after you add `id` and `endTime` as dependencies to the `useEffect` (*as mentioned in the comments of the OP*), it seems that the issue is that the first render you do of the first `Time` is done without/or with a wrong `endTime` so it end up displaying `NaN`.

Subsequent renders, I assume after fetching the data from somewhere, provide a valid `endTime` value for that property.

Initially the change in that prop would not alter the functionality of the ongoing interval, since the `getRemainingTime` would refer to the initial value of `endTime`.

There are a few solutions to this problem.

1. Do not render the `Timer` component until after you have valid data to provide to it. This need to be handled at the component using the `Timer` and not inside it.
2. Provide a `key` for the `Timer` component when using it (`<Timer key={/*what ever you use for id will most likely work here too*/} id={..} endTime={..} />` that is unique and would change once you get the data from the remote location.
3. Use correct dependencies for the `useEffect`.

For 3. the more correct approach is not to add `id` and `endTime` to the `useEffect` but to use `useCallback`, with `endTime` for the `getRemainingTime` and then use that as dependency for the `useEffect`.

```js
const getRemainingTime = useCallback(function() {
  const now = new Date();
  const end = new Date(endTime);
  const diff = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
  const days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  const minutes = Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  const seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
  return { days, hours, minutes, seconds };
}, [endTime]);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setRemainingTime(getRemainingTime());
  }, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [getRemainingTime]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem is handling of the data. The potential problem in your code is here. you need to console the diff before this line. **diff** can be 0 in a particular case. When diff will be 0 the statement written below will give you **NAN**

**const seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);**

---

**Fix you can try**

**const seconds = diff ? Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60) : 0 ;**

Comment: That changed the NaN to 0. It doesn't update after that. And the timer shows all 0 instead of the correct time left. Also, this issue is only for the top card.

Comment: @sidharthsunilkumar have you printed diff ? Can you tell me what diff is coming first card and what value is coming for other cards